# How to create a workflow in 2013 to send multiple email in a month

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I want to create a Designer Workflow in 2013 which will trigger the email automatically for 5 times in a month. List is same but the calculation and logic is different for every email. First time, i can initiate the process to send the email (ex-creating a button to initiate) then email will be sent after 2 days then after 4 days resp

For this, i used 2 things-

1. HTTP Web Service call- but it is giving me unexpected error. Even I am not able to fetch the list records.
2. created a JavaScript with set Timeout function. But the problem is How and where to deploy and schedule this script so it will run till the last email and trigger it automatically after some days based on the logic.

can anyone help me please?
or if there are any other solution, please share.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put JavaScript into a workflow.  SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflows have two built-in actions that will allow you to make it wait for a specified time.

- `Pause for Duration` - allows you to specify a length of time to wait before executing the next step.
- `Pause until Date` - allows you to specify a specify date/time in the future that the workflow should pause until that that date/time is reached.